# Getting error attempted to update component that has already been unmounted?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am fetching data from mongodb collection using react-meteor. I am passing `loading` as a prop to functional component. `loading` is bool value which will be true when entire data is ready to get fetched. I want to display content from JSON response on web page but I am getting error: attempted to update component that has already been unmounted.

Code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor";
import { withTracker } from "meteor/react-meteor-data";

const Header = ({ allnavitems, loading }) => {
  if (loading) {
    let navlist = allnavitems;

    console.log(navlist.length);
    console.log(navlist[0]);

    return (
      <div>
        <h3>{navlist[0]}</h3>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default withTracker(params => {
  const navitems = Meteor.subscribe("league_navbar", "");

  return {
    loading: navitems.ready(),
    allnavitems: NavigationItems.find().fetch()
  };
})(Header);
```

I tried above code but it gives error. What could be the possible reason ? In console I am getting the error: attempted to update component that has already been unmounted.

If I change above header component to following then I can only see Loading.. on web page but it should display navlist[0] after the data is fetched i.e loading is true.

```
const Header = ({allnavitems, loading}) => {

    if(loading){
        let navlist = allnavitems

        console.log(navlist.length)
        console.log(navlist[0])

    return(
        <div>
            <h3>{navlist[0]}</h3>         
        </div>
    )

    }else{
        return(
        <div><p>Loading...</p>
        </div>
        )
    }

}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Please show us the error message with its stack trace.

Comment: @trixn Check the screenshot in question

Comment: @trixn If I remove `return()` from the functional component then I am able to see the entire data but I also want to display content when loading is true i.e after entire data is fetched. Should I create `class` component instead of functional component.

Comment: Your `Header` component doesn't return anything if `loading` is `false`. A `React` component must always return something, even if it is `null`.

Comment: @AlexandreWiechersVaz Check updated code.

Comment: @trixn Check updated code.

Comment: Your definition of loading is very confusing: When `navitems.ready()` returns `true` then `loading` should be `false`. So it should always be the opposite of `navitems.ready()`.

Comment: @trixn I think the problem is because of I am using functional component. If I use class component then inside render() when the state changes i.e when loading changes it will render the data. Currently it is not working because I am using functional component which doesn;t have render. Am I correct ?

Comment: No this does not make a difference. A functional component **is** the render function. If a class based component has no state and only a `render()` function this is equivalent to a functional component.

Comment: Can't say for sure without a live example, but are you sure that `loading` is set to `true` at any given point?

Comment: If I don't use loading then I get fetched data twice once incomplete data is fetched and then during 2nd call the entire data is fetched. So I want to display content when entire data is fetched not when the data is incomplete.

Comment: `loading` should be mapped as `loading: !navitems.ready()` and your `Header` component should of course be rendering "Loading..." when `loading` is `true` and not the other way round.

Comment: @trixn Ok I changed loading to `loading: !navitems.ready()` but still it doesn't work why so ? Can you write an answer so that it will be clear

Comment: @trixn My ultimate goal is to access navlist data inside return()  but I am not able to do that.

Comment: Try `console.log(loading)` inside of your `Header` component. Does it log `false` at any time?

Comment: @trixn If loading is `loading: navlist.ready()` then I get `false` and then `true`.

Comment: @trixn  If loading is loading: !navlist.ready() then I get `true` and then `false`.

Comment: Okay that is expected. But please leave that as `!navlist.ready()`. And in your component you need to render the list when loading is **false**. Of course loading means that the request is still fetching and **no data is available yet**. You definded it the other way round which is confusing.

Comment: And then confirm that when `loading` is finally false, that `navitems` actually contains data.

Comment: @trixn Ok so what is possible solution ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177118/discussion-between-trixn-and-stone-rock).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't render objects with react. You may want to map over your nav items and render a link or something like that for each by unpacking each items properties that you care about:

```
const Header = ({ allnavitems, loading }) => {
    if (loading) return <div><p>Loading...</p></div>

    return (
      <div>
        {allnavitems.map(({heading, url}) => <a href={url}>{heading}</a>}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default withTracker(params => {
  const navitems = Meteor.subscribe("league_navbar", "");

  return {
    loading: !navitems.ready(), // it makes more sense to invert it because loading means that the items are *not* ready
    allnavitems: NavigationItems.find().fetch()
  };
})(Header);
```

Comment: One thing I couldn;t understand why loading is changed to loading: !navitems.ready() Why does !navitems.ready() work and why not navitems.ready() work ? Can you answer it in your answer